# What exactly CONS of the language do?

Tags: scheme, lisp, cons

What exactly CONS of the language scheme/LISP do?
like in this function for example:

```
 (DEFINE (guess list1 list2)
 (COND
 ((NULL? list1) '())
 ((member (CAR list1) list2)
 (CONS (CAR list1) (guess (CDR list1) list2)))
 (ELSE (guess (CDR list1) list2))
 ))
```

Comment: This is very easy to search for. (Keep in mind that Lisp and Scheme are different languages, though.)

Comment: Its the constructor of a singly linked list node, except its so general it's next pointer is not required to be a node. Such chain is displayed and read as a list.

Answer (score 0):

- Lisp: [`cons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cons.htm)
- Scheme: [`cons`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_240) and [Help explaining how `cons` in Scheme work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741111/850781)