# Racket: Make list of pairs from two lists

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a function that takes in two lists of atoms as a parameter and returns them as a list of pairs.

**Example Input**

`(combine '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c d e))`

**Example Output**

`'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d) (5 e))`

However, I'm new to Racket and can't seem to figure out the specific syntax to do so. Here is the program that I have so far:

```
(define connect
  (lambda (a b)
    (cond [(> (length(list a)) (length(list b))) (error 'connect"first list too long")]
          [(< (length(list a)) (length(list b))) (error 'connect"first list too short")]
          [else (cons (cons (car a) (car b)) (connect(cdr a) (cdr b)))]
     )))
```

When I run it, it gives me the error:

```
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: '()
```

Along with that, I don't believe the error checking here works either, because the program gives me the same error in the `else` statement when I use lists of different lengths.

Can someone please help? The syntax of `cons` doesn't make sense to me, and the documentation for Racket didn't help me solve this issue.

Comment: `(define (unzip . lists) (apply map list lists))`? Works with any number of arguments. If you use `map` from SRFI-1 it will  stop at the shortest list or signal an error with the standard `map`

Comment: What's the name of the procedure? you seem to be mixing things. Is it `connect`, `combine` or `zip`?

Comment: You don't have to call `list` on `a` or `b`, this is wrong: `(list a)`. This is because `a` is _already_ a list, why do you want to put it inside another list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're new to Scheme, you have to learn to write code in the way recommended for the language. You'll learn this through books, tutorials, etc. In particular, most of the time you want to use built-in procedures; as mentioned in the comments this is how you'd solve the problem in "real life":

```
(define (zip a b)
  (apply map list (list a b)))
```

Having said that, if you want to solve the problem by explicitly traversing the lists, there are a couple of things to have in mind when coding in Scheme:

- We traverse lists using recursion. A recursive procedure needs at least one base case and one or more recursive cases.
- A recursive step involves calling the procedure itself, something that's not happening in your solution.
- If we needed them, we create new helper procedures.
- We never use `length` to test if we have processed all the elements in the list.
- We build new lists using `cons`, be sure to understand *how* it works, because we'll recursively call `cons` to build the output list in our solution.
- The syntax of `cons` is very simple: `(cons 'x 'y)` just sticks together two things, for example the symbols `'x` and `'y`. By convention, a list is just a series of nested `cons` calls where the last element is the empty list. For example: `(cons 'x (cons 'y '()))` produces the two-element list `'(x y)`

Following the above recommendations, this is how to write the solution to the problem at hand:

```
(define (zip a b)
  ; do all the error checking here before calling the real procedure
  (cond
    [(> (length a) (length b)) (error 'zip "first list too long")]
    [(< (length a) (length b)) (error 'zip "first list too short")]
    [else (combine a b)])) ; both lists have the same length

(define (combine a b)
  (cond
    ; base case: we've reached the end of the lists
    [(null? a) '()]
    ; recursive case
    [else (cons (list (car a) (car b)) ; zip together one element from each list
                (combine (cdr a) (cdr b)))])) ; advance the recursion
```

It works as expected:

```
(zip '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c d e))
=> '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d) (5 e))
```

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense to me and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your error handling doesn't work is because you are converting your lists to a list with a single element. `(list '(1 2 3 4 5))` gives `'((1 2 3 4 5))` which length is 1. You need to remove the `list`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741668/6790541) is a good explanation of `cons`. You can use `cons` to build a list recursively in your case.

```lisp
(define connect
  (lambda (a b)
    (cond [(> (length a) (length b)) (error 'zip "first list too long")]
          [(< (length a) (length b)) (error 'zip "first list too short")]
          [(empty? a) '()]
          [else (cons (list (car a) (car b)) (connect (cdr a) (cdr b)))]
               )))
```

However, I would prefer [Sylwester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565698/sylwester)'s solution

```lisp
(define (unzip . lists) (apply map list lists))
```

which uses Racket's useful [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket
(define (combine lst1 lst2)
  (map list lst1 lst2))

;;; TEST
(combine '() '())
(combine (range 10) (range 10))
(combine (range 9) (range 10))
```

`map` have buildin check mechanism. We don't need to write check again.

```
#lang racket

(define (combine lst1 lst2)
  (local [(define L1 (length lst1))
          (define L2 (length lst2))]
    (cond
      [(> L1 L2)
       (error 'combine "first list too long")]
      [(< L1 L2)
       (error 'combine "second list too long")]
      [else (map list lst1 lst2)])))
```